# How to run a command on startup connection ssh with cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I have a machine with cygwin installed in and several disk mapped. When I start a connection like this:

```
ssh 10.120.10.11
```

... cygwin starts and the .mkshrc script is run which make these disks visible. But when I run a command directly like this:

```
ssh 10.120.10.11 "ls /cygwin"
```

...this script is not run and I can see the mapped disks. These is a problem since I want to run a script which install and point things to these mapped drives.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "ls /cygwin" | ssh 10.120.10.11
```